# jQuery function to run after another function is valid

Tags: jquery, validation

I am wanting to check if the email field is already stored within the database **after** the email address is valid. I have both functions working perfectly, how ever, both at the same time. I'm wanting the 'check if email is in database' function to run after the 'check if email is valid' becomes valid.

Email Validation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#SignUp").validate({
    rules:{
        email:{
            required:true,
            email:true
        },
    },
    messages:{
        email:{
            required:"Enter your email address",
            email:"Enter valid email address"
        },
        gender:"Select Gender"
    },
    errorClass: "help-inline",
    errorElement: "span",
    highlight:function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parents('.control-group').removeClass('error');
        $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('success');
    }
    });
});
```

Email Availability Check:

```
    $(function()
{
    $('#email').keyup(function()
    {
        var email=$(this).val();
        if(email!=''){
   //$('.check').show();
   $('error').fadeIn(400).html
   ('<img src="/img/ajax-loading.gif" />');
   var dataString = 'email='+ email;
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "pages/check_email.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){
        if(result=='Available'){
            $('.check').html(email+' Avaliable');
            $('#create').attr('disabled', '');
            $('#create').attr('value', 'Active');
            $("#email").removeClass("red");
            $("#email").addClass("white");
        }else{
            $('.check').html(email+' '+result);
            $('#create').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#create').attr('value', 'Deactive');
            $("#email").removeClass("white");
            $("#email").addClass("red");
        }
    }
   });
}else{
    $('.check').html('');
    $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#submit').attr('value', 'Deactive');
}
});
});
```

Is there some way of accessing the first function to check if email:true, and then call the second function?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot access a functions local variables from the outside.

You could inside the function create a closure and through that closure access it, but thats very different.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in function to jQuery Validate for this - called `remote`.  If you specify it like this:

```
$("#SignUp").validate({
rules:{
    email:{
        required:true,
        email:true,
        remote: 'pages/check_email.php'
    },
},
//rest of options
});
```

Then it will automatically send the `email` post variable to your `check_email.php` script.  Have that script return `"true"` or `"false"`.  I believe the default behaviour will check the email thing first, then send it to your AJAX script.  You can see an example of this here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/PdP69/  Note that on jsfiddle, you have to be a bit more complicated in specifying the remote page due to how the site works... Watch the console though and you'll see that it doesn't go to remote until the email address is valid.